.NET Core migration suddenly stopped working: error MSB1008
I have a simple project with a couple of migrations that ran successfully before already. I have opened the project today and I can't add any new migrations where I get the error: "MSB1008: Only one project can be specified".
The command that usually worked: dotnet ef migrations add "TestMigration" --project src/Infrastructure --startup-project src/WebUI --output-dir Persistence/Migrations
I have tried changing the folder where I run the command in, I have also tried changing the command parameters and switched to older branches, nothing seems to work anymore.
This is the full error that I get:

MSBUILD : error MSB1008: Only one project can be specified.
Full command line: 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.321\MSBuild.dll -maxcpucount -verbosity:m -restore -consoleloggerparameters:Summary ef migrations add Initial --project src/Infrastructure --startup-project src/WebUI --output-dir Persistence/Migrations -distributedlogger:Microsoft.DotNet.Tools.MSBuild.MSBuildLogger,C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.321\dotnet.dll*Microsoft.DotNet.Tools.MSBuild.MSBuildForwardingLogger,C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.321\dotnet.dll'
Switches appended by response files:
Switch: migrations

Any help is appreciated.

Could you do a dotnet ef migrations add "TestMigration" --project src/Infrastructure --startup-project src/WebUI --output-dir Persistence/Migrations --verbose. Then we can see more details.

And do you have access to Persistence/Migrations from where you executed the command?

Check for Spaces and Quotation Marks
dotnet ef migrations add "TestMigration" --project "src/Infrastructure" --startup-project "src/WebUI" --output-dir "Persistence/Migrations"

Or
Run the command with full paths
dotnet ef migrations add "TestMigration" --project "C:/path/to/your/solution/src/Infrastructure" --startup-project "C:/path/to/your/solution/src/WebUI" --output-dir "Persistence/Migrations"

